# Random children placement in gridlayout

Tags: android

Hey guys I have 26 buttons nicely arranged in a gridlayout but I am trying to achieve something. I want the buttons to shuffle and place themselves randomly in cell positions in the grid layout on a button click. AND none  of them should be placed above another. Please can this be achieved? All suggestions are welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you should try to do something and show your code where you gone stack. None would do work on behalf of you!

Answer (score 0):

`GridLayout` child positioning is solemnly bound to child index.

Which means to achieve random positioning all you need is randomly change child positions by using [ViewGroup.addView(View, int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#addView(android.view.View, int)) and [View.removeViewAt(int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#removeViewAt(int))

As for not placing above each other, the grid layout child distribution takes care of all this.

Answer (score 0):

I finally did it. I just had to create a Random variable, remove each view and place them at a new random index